# Move image content using units

Tags: css

Let's assume my image size is 960x960 but height of `img` element is 720px.

```
<img class="imgs" src="~/test.jpg" />
```

styles for `.imgs`

```
.imgs {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45rem;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

And now I can use `object-position` to set position top/bot or other, but can I move this img using some units?
I'll try to explain this using paint (sorry for my paint skills):

Legend:
black line - div, red line - img

When I would use `object-posotion: top` it looks like:

[obj-pos-bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgXO6.png)

When use `object-position: bottom`:

[obj-pos-top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZmNr.png)

And now how I want to move it:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMWzN.png)

So I want `object-position: top`, but also move the image content a little bit up (few pixels). I've tried with margin and padding but it's moving whole element not only the content

Comment: `transform:translate()`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to align your image content within the element's box.
You can actually achieve this with `object-position`.

Just use the unit you want to use instead of the values `top, bottom, etc.`; for exmaple:

```
object-position: 50% 10px;
```

The first value sets the horizontal position, the second value sets the vertical position.